# How to let the express route use my mocked module not the main one when I send req to it using supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to mock a `uploadImage` middleware function In which:-

I access it in user route so I need when I send a request using supertest to `/users/me/avatar` in user route it uses the mocked `uploadImage` not the main one

where should I put the mocked `uploadImage` module

...

the path of `uploadImage` module >> `/middlewares/uploadImage.js`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution for my problem but not an answer for my question ..

you can use environment variables to deal with that as when you run npm test it run the `test.env` you specified for the tests

and when you `npm run start` or (`npm run dev`) as your implement of the package.json file you use the `dev.env` to (in my case) change between the unreal path for avatars uploads and the original one